# How to Insert Records only if 2+ records are returned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, group-by, having

So I have this fun little loop that looks for duplicate addresses.  I finally tweaked to run quite fast, however I can't quite get what I need from it.

[Sample Data and Expected Results](https://pastebin.com/75zmkesQ)

Here is the loop:

```
WHILE @cnt <= @max
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @customer_id=[customer_id],
            @add1   =[add1], 
            @add2   =[add2], 
            @add3   =[add3], 
            @zip    =[zip]
          FROM #tmpCustomers
          WHERE [id] = @cnt

        -- Ensures customer_id is not already in the dupeCustomerAddress table
        IF NOT EXISTS( SELECT [customer_id] FROM dupeCustomerAddress WHERE [customer_id] = @customer_id )
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dupeCustomerAddress
                SELECT
                    [customer_id],
                    [address1],
                    [add1],
                    [address2],
                    [add2],
                    [address3],
                    [add3],
                    [zip]
                  FROM [working_customerAddress]
                  WHERE
                    -- Removes the Record used for comparison
--                  [customer_id] != @customer_id AND
                    -- Don't need to include records already processed
                    [customer_id] > @cnt AND
                    (
                        (       -- Address Line 1 or 2 matches Comparison Line 1 AND Zip matches
                            (
                              ( [address1] IS NOT NULL AND [add1] = @add1 ) OR  
                              ( [address2] IS NOT NULL AND [add2] = @add1 ) 
                            ) AND [zip] = @zip
                        )
                        OR
                        (       -- Address Line 1 or 2 matches Comparison Line 2 AND Zip matches
                            (
                              ( [address1] IS NOT NULL AND [add1] = @add2 ) OR  
                              ( [address2] IS NOT NULL AND [add2] = @add2 ) 
                            ) AND [zip] = @zip
                        )
                    )
                    GROUP BY customer_id, add1, add2, add3, address1, address2, address3, zip
                    HAVING COUNT(customer_id) > 1
                    
    
        END 
        SET @cnt = @cnt + 1 
    END
```

If I remove the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` then it returns every row since #tmpCustomers is just a subset of fields from working_customerAddress.  Which makes sense.

If I uncomment `[customer_id] != @customer_id` then it gives me only the duplicate record info, not the source record info.  So if b and c are duplicates of a, I only get b and c but I want a, b and c.

I tried adding the `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` but then I get no results at all.
All of the records should be unique since it's just one `per customer_id`, so the `GROUP BY` shouldn't be an issue.  Maybe the `HAVING` isn't right.

What am I missing?

I'm running the latest version of MS SQL Server and SSMS

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement are actually more useful than code that does *not* do what you want.

Comment: I am confused about your data set as well, need some sample data to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @GordonLinoff What's the best way to include the sample data?  Copy/Paste from Excel doesn't look so good.

Comment: @Alex Added link to sample data: https://pastebin.com/75zmkesQ